# Background view freezes after opening the share view

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

So I have an app and a share extension. For the share extension I have just one simple controller that extends `UIViewController` and not `SLComposeServiceViewController` (I believe the default view is too complicated for what I am trying to do). What i'm trying to achieve inside the extension is to get some data from `UserDefaults`, make some `HTTP` requests and show an alert with the `HTTP` response. The share extension should only be used inside a browser, but after I tap the extension the browser view freezes and after I dismiss the alert the browser is still frozen. How and where I should dismiss the alert or the parent view?

I'm new to this environment but I did some research and I believe this has something to do with the view hierarchy but I'm not sure, here is the controller:

```
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a duplicate and I'm not sure if I should answer here as well. Sorry for not searching enough. For swift 3:

```
self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: this is not always work, i've tried tried a custom view and share a pdf from safari, the share extension view still exists